How to Create a Menu with List Sliding Animation
I need to create a menu that works this way: when you hover over a menu item, a list appears at the bottom of menu item. When I move the mouse to another element, the list smoothly slides to that element and changes items inside.



.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, min-content);
  column-gap: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.content-item {
  padding: 10px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">Item1</li>
    <li class="menu-item">Item2</li>
    <li class="menu-item">Item3</li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-item">thing1</div>
    <div class="content-item">thing1</div>
    <div class="content-item">thing1</div>
  </div>
</div>




As the lists may have different lengths as well as different text could yov describe in more detail exactly what the transition is to look like? At what point is the new height taken up and at what point does the text change. Is it to be gradual as the cursor moves to the new menu item, a sort of fade in and out effect or is it sudden when the cursor reaches the new menu item?

I will try to explain. When I hover over a menu item, a list appears below. It is aligned to the left edge of the menu item. When I move the cursor to the another menu item, the list does not disappear but it slides under the menu to item on which the cursor is hovering. And at the same time, the contents of the list smoothly disappear, and new content appears in its place. The list container itself moves and its contents change smoothly. When I leave menu the list disappear.

I have used JavaScript for this type of menu because it cannot be implemented without JavaScript. Please check my example below:


// script.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li');
    const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
    
    const dropdownContent = {
        item1: ['Option A1', 'Option B1', 'Option C1'],
        item2: ['Option A2', 'Option B2', 'Option C2'],
        item3: ['Option A3', 'Option B3', 'Option C3']
    };

    menuItems.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
            const dropdownList = dropdown.querySelector('ul');
            dropdownList.innerHTML = '';
            const data = dropdownContent[item.getAttribute('data-dropdown')];
            data.forEach(option => {
                const li = document.createElement('li');
                li.textContent = option;
                dropdownList.appendChild(li);
            });

            dropdown.style.display = 'block';
            const rect = item.getBoundingClientRect();
            dropdown.style.left = `${rect.left}px`;
        });

        item.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            dropdown.style.display = 'none';
        });
    });

    dropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        dropdown.style.display = 'block';
    });

    dropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        dropdown.style.display = 'none';
    });
});
/* styles.css */
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu li {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;

    left: 0;
    display: none;
    width: 200px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    transition: left 0.3s ease;
}

.dropdown ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.dropdown ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown ul li:hover {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
  
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li data-dropdown="item1" class="menu-item">Item1</li>
            <li data-dropdown="item2" class="menu-item">Item2</li>
            <li data-dropdown="item3" class="menu-item">Item3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    

    <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <ul class="content">
            <li class="content-item">Option A1</li>
            <li class="content-item">Option B1</li>
            <li class="content-item">Option C1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>




Thank you But this doesn't work the way I need it. I dont' want content block to disappear when I hover on another menu item, I want it to slide to right.

@uiHellen Thank you so much for your opinion. I have updated my answer please check this one and let me know. I think, this will solve your problem. Thanks
